# Update the title of a UIButton from a UIPickerView from another controller

Tags: ios, uibutton, uipickerview

I have a `ViewController` called `NotepadView.h/.m` with a `UIButton` that has the title "User: (Select)". Once the user touches the button, a `UIPickerView` appears as a popover, which is initialized from `UserPickerViewController.h/.m`. Once the button is clicked, the proper rows appear in the picker. But after an `IBAction` is implemented (tapping the button, choosing the correct row form the picker, then leaving the picker) the button title only updates after the button is pressed again.

I know this is because I am using a `touch up inside` action, so once the button is touched, the title is immediately changed to "User: (null)" until it is touched a second time after the proper row has been selected in the picker. How do I implement an action so that when the picker row is selected, it immediately changes the button title, instead of filling it with "User: (null)" until i touch it again?

Also, how would I go about exiting the `UserPickerViewController.m` after the row is selected, and segueing back to the `NotepadView.m` besides touching outside of the picker view?

`NotepadView.m` under `viewDidLoad`:

```
[_userBTN setTitle: @"User: (Select)" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Under an `IBAction` of touch up inside:

```
- (IBAction)refreshUsername:(id)sender {
    [_userBTN setTitle: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"User: %@",gUserInfo.chosenUserName] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

In  `UserPickerViewController.m`:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

NSArray *userArray = [gUserInfo availableUsers];
gUserInfo.chosenUserName = [userArray objectAtIndex:row];

}
```

Comment: what is `gUserInfo` in the second function?

Comment: Thats an object with a property `chosenUserName` so that I can access the array across all my controllers/ @Danqing

Comment: Where is it declared? Is it global?

Comment: yes, it is global and it is working properly, because I can see my array of usernames in the picker @danqing

Comment: Have you tried setting the button title in the pickerView didSelectRow method?

Comment: I cannot access the button from my pickerView since the two are in two separate viewControllers. If there is a way to do this, I would love to know! @JasonMcDermott

Comment: I would suggest you try passing the data back to the first view controller with an unwind segue. Here's an example http://natashatherobot.com/ios-pass-data-unwind-segue/

Comment: I changed my design so that there is a save button, so the segueing idea worked with that bar button! Thank you! @JasonMcDermott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JasonMcDermott recommended, I changed my `UserPickerViewController.m` to contain a `UIBarButton` called "Save". Once the button is pressed, using an `unwindSegue`, the string from the picker row, is stored in a variable named `user`, which is then transferred over to the `NotepadView.m` upon `touchUpInside`.